# React-boostrap Popover not stay with button on scroll container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I recreated popover in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-grothendieck-bwoqu?file=/src/App.js) here, follow the [documentation code](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/popovers/#popovers-in-container), the popover show up, but after scroll, the pointer does not align with the button anymore, I tried to pass `container` prop, but still not working. How can I solve this?

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Click the button
2. Popover show up
3. Scroll in the container
4. Popover follows the scrolling event instead of element.

[image: Screen Shot 2021-11-06 at 10 42 56 PM]

### Reproducible Example

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-grothendieck-bwoqu?file=/src/App.js)

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Popover,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Button,
  ButtonToolbar
} from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const popoverBottom = (
  <Popover id="popover-positioned-scrolling-bottom" title="Popover bottom">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
  </Popover>
);

const popoverRight = (
  <Popover id="popover-positioned-scrolling-right" title="Popover right">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
  </Popover>
);

export default class Positioner extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="bs-example-popover-scroll">
        <ButtonToolbar style={{ padding: "100px 0" }}>
          <OverlayTrigger
            container={this}
            trigger="click"
            placement="bottom"
            overlay={popoverBottom}
          >
            <Button>Bottom guacamole!</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
          <OverlayTrigger
            container={this}
            trigger="click"
            placement="right"
            overlay={popoverRight}
          >
            <Button>Right guacamole!</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

styles.css

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.bs-example-popover-scroll {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

### Expected behavior

A popover should stay with a button element instead of scrolling container.
A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.

[image: Screen Shot 2021-11-06 at 10 33 06 PM]

### Environment

- Operating System: Catalina 10.15.7
- Browser, Version  chrome Version 95.0.4638.54
- React-Bootstrap Version 0.33.1 (Same from the documentation)

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code you've an issue with as a properly formatted code snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right. Since popover is an absolute div, it is positioned relative to the parent element with position relative. since you have not mentioned parent div(.bs-example-popover-scroll) as relative, the popover is positioned with respect to the document so it doesn't adjust as per scroll.

just add position relative to div.bs-example-popover-scroll and it work

[modified code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-popover-with-scroll-64chh)

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Popover,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Button,
  ButtonToolbar
} from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const popoverBottom = (
  <Popover id="popover-positioned-scrolling-bottom" title="Popover bottom">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
  </Popover>
);

const popoverRight = (
  <Popover id="popover-positioned-scrolling-right" title="Popover right">
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
  </Popover>
);

export default class Positioner extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="bs-example-popover-scroll"
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <ButtonToolbar style={{ padding: "100px 0" }}>
          <OverlayTrigger
            container={this}
            trigger="click"
            placement="bottom"
            overlay={popoverBottom}
          >
            <Button>Bottom guacamole!</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
          <OverlayTrigger
            container={this}
            trigger="click"
            placement="right"
            overlay={popoverRight}
          >
            <Button>Right guacamole!</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This work in my example code. What if the popover div is not child of the components, then use ref should work? Thank you

Comment: that will be the only way to work. docs also mention about same https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/popovers/#popovers-in-container